# What is the difference between heating and cooling, fundamentally?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, temperature, everyday-life

**Context:** My physics friend told me that heating and cooling effects are identical if you flip the vertical coordinates accordingly. If you heat a room from below, the warm air rises. Identically, air sinks if you cool the ceiling (which is like heating if you are looking at it upside down).

**Problem:** I don't have a good background in fluid mechanics, and (likely because of that) I find it difficult to believe that just a vertical coordinate flipping would capture everything.

**Root of the problem:** When you heat a surface, there is convection, turbulence, eddies, etc in the fluid above it. When you cool the surface, the motion is much less turbulent and laminar (this could be a misconception). I doubt whether these dynamical differences will be captured just by vertical coordinate flipping.

**Question:**

1. So, is there a fundamental difference between the way heating and
   cooling work on a fluid?
2. Is it just a reversal of the temperature
   gradient and flipping of vertical coordinates, or is there something
   more to it?

Comment: It has more to do with the fact that gravity acts in one direction - downward. When the air is cool, gravity pulls it down more thus pushing the warmer air higher. Note that cooler air has a higher density than warmer air, and that is why it is pulled down displacing the warm air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heating and cooling were originally thought to be different things.  The equations for them were derived differently.  Eventually it was discovered that they are the same mechanism, but in opposite directions. (James Maxwell)

What you describe, however, is more than *just* heating or cooling.  When you talk of warm air rising, you are also talking about mass transport.  In such a situation, opposite directions can behave differently, just as how if you are facing a wall, taking a step backwards or a step forward is different.  Even though both of them are just a displacement, in opposite directions, one can cause you to stub your toe while the other cannot.  That being said, it is very trivial to make examples where they do indeed behave symmetrically.  The room you describe is *almost* one such example (there's a second-order effect of viscosity being different on cooler fluids, but I believe that is utterly negligible in the case of gases.  It might be more of an issue for liquid examples)

While it is not possible to give a definitive reason for why your particular intuition, because we are not you, one experiment that might be worth looking into is looking at how the smoke from incense moves.  If the air in a room is still, incense smoke can travel upwards in a surprisingly laminar flow for a long time before the transition to turbulence occurs.  You can also look into [incence waterfalls](https://www.walmart.com/c/kp/waterfall-incense).<sup>*</sup>  In these cases, the smoke particles are permitted to cool first, and they instead flow downward.   Observing these examples may be helpful for adjusting your intuition to better align with what the empirical evidence of science provides.

<sup>*</sup>.  I am not affiliated with this commercial link.  It is extremely difficult to find a link describing this sort of product which is not selling one.  The link here was chosen because it was high up on Google's search list and because it provided examples of several products.

Answer (score 2):

I concur with the opinion in the comment: when the setup is on (the surface of the) Earth then gravity introduces a vertical bias.

To remove that vertical bias: put the setup in orbit, so that there is no gravitational bias.

To heat the air in the room:
Cause the air in the room to convect along a surface that is warmer than the air; heat will transfer from that warmer surface to the air.

To chill the air in the room:
Cause the air in the room to convect along a surface that is colder than the air; heat will transfer from the air to that colder surface.

(In the absence of gravitational bias convection does not happen spontaneously, so using fans to cause motion of the air helps. Without motion of the air the transfer will still occur of course, but much slower.)

Comment: This seems all nice and fair, but how does it answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

So, if you would assume a spacially constant field of gravity, that linearly depends on the density, and you would further assume that the density change would be linear with temperature, assuming ideal gas formula for example. Then I do not see, why the fluid dynamics of the system heated at one side would differ from the system being cooled at the other side.

Once you do include either a spacially non constant or density wise nonlinear force field or use a nonlinear dependency of the volume from the temperature. That won’t be that case anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In your root problem, it is indeed a misconception that cooling down a fluid unconditionally reduces turbulence. Indeed, if you cool it at the top, the fluid will sink so you’ll have the similar Rayleigh-Taylor instabilities and downwards plumes.

You can formalize this mathematically in the simple setting of Rayleigh-Bénard convection (perhaps what your friend had in mind). Considering the velocity field $u$, pressure field $p$ and temperature field $T$, in Boussinesq approximation:
$$
\begin{align}
\partial_t u+(u\cdot\nabla)u &= \sqrt{\frac{Pr}{Ra}}\Delta u -\nabla p+Te_z\\
\partial_t T+(u\cdot\nabla)T &= \frac1{\sqrt{Pr Ra}}\Delta T
\end{align}
$$
with pressure determined by the incompressibility condition:
$$
\nabla\cdot u=0
$$
I’m using dimensionless quantities, so you just have two dimensionless parameters $Ra, Pr$ (Rayleigh and Prandtl numbers).

The heating can be modeled by the thermal boundary conditions. The simplest one is Dirichlet:
$$
\begin{align}
T(z=1)&=0 & T(z=0)&=1
\end{align}
$$

Now you can formalize the symmetry. If you flip the vertical direction:
$$
z\to 1-z
$$
Then you need to transform your fields as:
$$
\begin{align}
u_x&\to u_x & u_y&\to u_y & u_z&\to -u_z\\
T&\to 1-T & p&\to p-z
\end{align}
$$
So that they are still solutions to the same problem. The operation on $T$ is the mathematical translation of flipping hot and cold.

You can formalize this symmetry with different boundary conditions (Neumann by fixing heat flux, Newton convective cooling etc.). Note that the mathematical treatement heavily relies on the simplifying assumptions of the model. For example, if you take into account the decrease of viscosity and diffusivity in temperature, then yes you could expect more turbulence on the hot side which cannot be compensated by flipping gravity (this is not captured by the Boussinesq equations which assume constant $Ra,Pr$).

Hope this helps.